# Find the equation of the locus of the mid-point of the normal to a tangent

Tags: conic-sections, tangent-line

Find the equation to the normal of the curve $x=2t, y=t^2$ at the point with parameter $t$. If this normal meets the x- and y-axes at points A and B respectively, find the equation of the locus of the mid-point of AB.

I have said:

$x=2t, y= t^2$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = t$

$\rightarrow$ gradient of the normal is $\frac{-1}{t}$

$\rightarrow \frac{y-t^2}{x-2t}=\frac{-1}{t} \rightarrow x+ty=t^3 +2t$

At point A, $y=0, x=t^3 + 2t$

At point B, $x=0, y=t^2+2$

The coordinates of the mid point are $[\frac{t^3+2t}{2},\frac{t^2+2}{2}]$

But where to go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got till the point that locus of midpoint is $ \displaystyle \left [2x = t^3+2t, 2y = t^2+2\right]$

$2y = t^2+2 \implies t = \pm \sqrt{2y-2}$

$2x = t^3+2t = t \ (t^2 + 2) = (\pm \sqrt{2y-2}) \ 2y$

$x^2 = (2y-2) y^2 \implies 2y^3 - 2y^2 = x^2$

Here is a diagram of the parabola curve and locus of the midpoint of intersection of its normal lines with  with x and y axes.

[image]

Comment: You are welcome. Just added a diagram.

Comment: Sure, I will also suggest that as you are currently studying conic section, you should also add that tag to the questions you ask. It is a more watched tag I believe. I have added for this one.

Comment: Thank you.  A very useful piece of advice.